# Spring, load bean with specific dependency

Tags: java, spring

Is it possibile to load a bean (scope "prototype") telling Spring to create it using a specific dependency?

Example:

- the dependencies, "StoreA" and "StoreB"
- the bean I want to load, "Service"

can I tell Spring to load "Service" sometimes with "StoreA" and sometimes with "StoreB"?

Actually the only solution I've found is to load two different application contexts each one with a common set of `<include .../>` directives and a specific one where I've declared the stores (so each application context has one declaration of store). Can I do the same thing using a single application context?

Comment: Why don't you create two service instances with different dependencies?

Comment: Sounds like you're after @Profiles.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to specific beans using their id, so when Autowiring use the

```
 @Qualifer("someBeanId")
```

or within a spring context use 'ref'/'ref-local'

Answer (score 1):

In situations like this I've most often used a [FactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html).  The getObject() method can define how you want to decide which store is loaded.